# Best way to only get some functionality from TextEdit for NSTextViews

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, textview, document

I'm new to objective-C and I'm not sure what's the best way to finish my current project. Basicaly, my project is a plugin for a medical software and it has as inputs 2 NSTextViews. I've tried to manually implement all the functionality of a text editor but some futures seem impossible for me to implement. My question is, what is the best way to get this functionality: [TextEdit Funtionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRF6v.jpg) for my NSTextViews ? Is there a better and/or easier way from doing every button and every action regarding text editing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for [NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview?language=objc), specifically the section "Using Text Formatting Controls".

The properties `rulerVisible` and `usesInspectorBar` will enable the functionality in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!